# Creating an Update method in a Repository - attaching/detaching entities not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following Update method:

```
        public Folder UpdateFolder(Folder folder)
        {
            _db.Folders.Attach(folder); // error happens here
            var entry = _db.Entry(folder);
            entry.Property(e => e.Title).IsModified = true;
            SaveChanges();
            return entry.Entity;
        }
```

I get "An object with the same key already exists" when I try to Attach.  If I remove that line, I get "The entity of type "folder" does not exist in this context".

I then try the following:

```
    public Folder UpdateFolder(Folder folder)
    {


        var entry = _db.Entry(folder);
        entry.State= EntityState.Detached;
        _db.Folders.Attach(folder);

        entry.Property(e => e.Title).IsModified = true;
```

And I get the same error when I hit the call to Attach.

Here's where I'm calling it from (test method):

```
        // Update Folder, Check Folder
        homeFolder.Title = "Updated";
        _dtoServices.UpdateFolder(homeFolder); // HERE
        Assert.AreEqual(_dtoServices.GetFolder(homeFolder.FolderId).Details, "Updated");
```

In my DtoServices:

```
        public FolderDto UpdateFolder(FolderDto folderDto)
        {     
            var test = _repository.UpdateFolder(folderDto.ToEntity());
            return null;
        }
```

In my FolderDto:

```
public class FolderDto
{
    public FolderDto()
    {
    }

    public FolderDto(Folder folder)
    {
        FolderId = folder.FolderId;
        Title = folder.Title;          
    }

    [Key]
    public int FolderId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Folder ToEntity()

     {
        var folder = new Folder
        {
            FolderId = FolderId,
            Title = Title,
        };
        return folder;
    }
 }
```

Any idea why this happening?  How can I build a more robust check for my update method?  I've searched around but can't find anything conclusive.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the entity isn't already attached.  I do something like this (TEntity : class):

```
...
//See if entity is attached already and return if so.    
TEntity attached = GetAttached(entityToUpdate);

if(attached == null)
{
  //Entity is not attached, attach it.
}      
...

//Generic helper to check for attached entity
private TEntity GetAttached(TEntity aEntity)
{
  var lObjectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
  EntityKey lKey = GetEntityKey(aEntity);

  ObjectStateEntry entry;
  if (!lObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(lKey, out entry)) return null;

  if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached) return null;

  return (TEntity)entry.Entity;
}
```